# Visualize function dependency by source files

Tags: c++, doxygen, graphviz

Need to know how much tied to each other my source files. For this reason I need to get dependency graph on function related to other source files level.

For this reason I'm using `Doxygen` with `Graphviz`. I have two files:

tst_no_make.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int  helloanotherfile(int);

void insidehello(int a)
{
    a=5;
}

void hello(int a)
{

    insidehello(a);
    int b= helloanotherfile(a);
    a=5;
}

void hello2(int a)
{
    int b= helloanotherfile(a);
    a=5;
}

int main() {
    hello(5);
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

anotherfile.cpp

```
int helloanotherfile(int a)
{
    return a;
}
```

Run doxygen with dot.exe and got nice output:

[image]

```
                   <-callhelloanotherfile
 helloanotherfile  <-hello<-main
                   <-hello2
```

But how to see all calls to functions in anotherfile.cpp from external files? I even not need whole call graph, I just need to see how often my function was used from other source files. In other words I don't want to see **callhelloanotherfile** function since it is from the same source file.

Comment: Did you try to place the line "int  helloanotherfile(int);" in a separate file another.h and include this file? I think that this is also a more common approach.

Comment: I revisited the question and I'm wondering where the `callhelloanotherfile` comes from, is it in anotherfile.cpp? if so does this also mean that you don't want to see in the picture of the function `hello` the reference to/from `main` ?